# Kusto query from runbook

Tags: analytics, azure-data-explorer, azure-runbook

Is it possible to call a kusto query against azure log analytics from a runbook?
I want to get back a scalar result.

Any examples?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible. Short answer to accomplish this requirement is by leveraging [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.operationalinsights/invoke-azoperationalinsightsquery?view=azps-4.7.0) cmdlet or [this](https://dev.loganalytics.io/documentation/Using-the-API/RequestFormat) API.

[This](https://dev.loganalytics.io/) is another reference for the above mentioned API.

You may call above mentioned cmdlet from a runbook or else you may call above mentioned API from a runbook with the help of [Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7) cmdlet.